# Parsing a file that has a parameter and a value

Tags: powershell, parsing

I'm a bit struggling trying to find the best way to parse this :

```
Secure Boot = Enabled;[Optional:Disabled = Enabled]
Network Offline Locker = Disabled;[Optional:Disabled = Enabled]
Chassis Intrusion Detection = Disabled;[Optional:Disabled = Enabled]
Configuration Change Detection = Disabled;[Optional:Disabled = Enabled]
Password Count Exceeded Error = Enabled;[Optional:Disabled = Enabled]
CSM = Disabled;[Optional:Disabled = Enabled]
Boot Up Num-Lock Status = On;[Optional:Off = On]
```

I need to have it so $Config and $ConfigValue are for example :

```
$Config
Secure Boot
$ConfigValue
Enabled;[Optional:Disabled = Enabled]
```

So the configuration name is left of " = " and it's value is right of the " = ".

I'm doing this for now and it seems to work fine :

```
  (Get-Content "File.ini") | ForEach-Object {

      #Isolate parameter (what is left of " = ")
      $Config =  ($_ -split " = ")[0]

      #Isolate value of parametre (what is right of " = ")
     $ConfigValue = ($_ -split " = ")[1]
}
```

Does that make the most sense? It's working fine but i'm always curious to find different ways to analyze it.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to use a PSCustomObject like this:

```
Get-Content -Path D:\sample\File.ini |
ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Config      = ($_ -split '=')[0].Trim()
        ConfigValue = (($_ -split '=')[1..10].Trim()) -join '='
    }
}
```

I assume that you don't have more than 10 equal signs in your ini file.  ;-)

You have a string with 2 (or more) equal signs in it. But you just want to split it on the first one. So you split the string on each equal sign, use the first part as the first part and join the rest of them as the second part. Therefor you re-join them with an equal sign again.

Comment: Good idea, both our methods don't grab the whole value though, since the value on the right can contain another " = ", so it ends up being "Enabled;[Optional:Disabled" instead of "Enabled;[Optional:Disabled = Enabled]" any idea how to prevent this? It doesn't break functionality fortunatly but i would like to be able to grab the whole value.

Comment: You're right. I didn't pay attention to the second "=". Changed the code. Try again now please.

Comment: Yeah this is perfect, do you mind explaining how adding 1..10 and -join grabs it?

Comment: i'm especially confused about the -join '='

Comment: Added explanation in my answer. Does that make sense for you?